# ValueError: Layer weight shape (3, 3, 3, 64) not compatible with provided weight shape (64, 3, 3, 3)

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to Classify products based on images and text, but running into errors

```
 img_width, img_height = 224, 224
# build the VGG16 network
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3), name='image_input'))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv1_1'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='conv1_2'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))


# set trainable to false in all layers
for layer in model.layers:
    if hasattr(layer, 'trainable'):
        layer.trainable = False

return model

WEIGHTS_PATH='E:/'
weight_file = ''.join((WEIGHTS_PATH, '/vgg16_weights.h5'))
f = h5py.File(weight_file,mode='r')
for k in range(f.attrs['nb_layers']):
    if k >= len(model.layers):
        # we don't look at the last (fully-connected) layers in the savefile
        break
    g = f['layer_{}'.format(k)]
    weights = [g['param_{}'.format(p)] for p in range(g.attrs['nb_params'])]
    model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)
f.close()
return model

load_weights_in_base_model(get_base_model())
```

error:
   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 1217, in 
  set_weights 'provided weight shape ' + str(w.shape))
ValueError: Layer weight shape (3, 3, 3, 64) not compatible with provided weight shape (64, 3, 3, 3)

can any one please help me to resolve the error. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example so that users can debug the problem. Also, did you make sure that the dimensions match? (3,3,3,64) is not (64,3,3,3) !

Answer (score 5):

The problem seems to be with the line

```
model.layers[k].set_weights(weights)
```

Keras initializes weights differently with different backends. If you are using `theano` as a backend, then weights will be initialized acc. to `kernels_first` and if you are using `tensorflow` as a backend, then weights will be initialized acc. to `kernels_last`.

So, the problem in you case seems to be that you are using `tensorflow` but are loading weights from a file which was created using `theano` as backend. The solution is to reshape your kernels using the keras `conv_utils`

```
from keras.utils.conv_utils import convert_kernel
reshaped_weights = convert_kernel(weights)
model.layers[k].set_weights(reshaped_weights)
```

Check [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/wiki/Converting-convolution-kernels-from-Theano-to-TensorFlow-and-vice-versa) out for more information

Comment: hey, I am using Theano backend but it is still showing me the same error. I was using Tensorflow before and now I changed to Theano. When I run your solution in tensorflow it gives me an error ('Invalid kernel shape:', (0,)). Do you know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved similar error by converting image to RGB.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).