# ValueError: Layer weight shape (3, 3, 3, 64) not compatible with provided weight shape (64, 3, 3, 3) when using keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I have the same error described in [ValueError: Layer weight shape (3, 3, 3, 64) not compatible with provided weight shape (64, 3, 3, 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283625/valueerror-layer-weight-shape-3-3-3-64-not-compatible-with-provided-weight)

When I used :

```
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
```

I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'
```

When I used an other solution:

```
from keras.utils.conv_utils import convert_kernel
reshaped_weights = convert_kernel(weights)
model.layers[k].set_weights(reshaped_weights)
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 11, in load_model_weights
  File "/home/khawkha/.virtualenvs/DeepMS/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 78, in convert_kernel
    raise ValueError('Invalid kernel shape:', kernel.shape)
ValueError: ('Invalid kernel shape:', (0,))
```

keras version: '2.3.1'
Tensorflow version: 1.15.0

Answer (score -2):

i think the first valueerror may be caused by different versions of keras.The keras of the model weights file are different from the keras you call.